Is it safe to flip the use of resistor pins of the INA106 differential amplifier to turns its gain from 10 into 0.1?
I'd like to have differential amplifier with gain of 0.1 without having to put any external resistor. Most of them in the datasheet states the use of gain of 1 or more and rarely specify the use of gain less than 1.
In the case of INA143 however, it states that you can flip the use of resistors pin to make the original gain of 10 into 0.1.

Now what if I use INA106 to do the same? Is it safe? Is there any caveat?

Did you ask TI? What did they say? Figure 5 of the data sheet shows that for R3/R4 "flipping" is possible, this can be a hint that it is also possible for R1/R2.

As said above it looks like it's possible. I am not sure I would trust the tiny on-chip resistors to be stable or reliable with 100V across them though, as they suggest.

@thebusybee No I haven't, thanks I just realized that.

@SpehroPefhany So the area of the diamond plot will be less? Any approximation?

In normal operation with relatively high bipolar supplies (+/-15 or +/-12j it would be difficult to get saturation or exceed the input CM range. Even with +/-5V supplies the non inverting input could go to about +/- 38V.

@busybee In the linked datasheet it's figure 2 that shows flipping R3/R4.
